# Is there a way to quickly extract specified tables into a different HDF5 file?

Tags: hdf5

Problem that I am trying to solve is the following - I have a long running Python (can take many hours to finish) process that produces up to 80000 HDF5 files. As one of the bottlenecks is constant opening and closing of these files I decided to write a proof-of-concept code that uses a single HDF5 file as output that contains many tables. It certainly helps but I wonder if there is a quick(er) way to export specified tables (with renaming if possible) into a separate file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are at least 3 ways to copy the contents of a dataset from one HDF5 file to another. They include:

1. `h5copy` command line utility from **The HDF Group**. You specify source and destination HDF5 files, along with source and destination objects. Likely this does exactly what you want without a lot of coding.
   Ref: [HDF Group: H5Copy docs](https://portal.hdfgroup.org/display/HDF5/h5copy)
2. **h5py** module has a `copy()` method for groups and/or datasets.  You input source and destination objects.
3. **pytables** module (aka tables) has a `copy_node()` method. A node is a group and/or a dataset.  You input source and destination objects.

If you choose to use `h5py`, there are a couple of relevant posts on SO:

- [How to copy a partial or skeleton h5py file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54579225/10462884)
- [How to partially copy using python an Hdf5 file into a new one
  keeping the same structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24532983/10462884)